# MySQL filter on multiple rows on associated table

Tags: mysql, sql

Using MySQL, is there an efficient way to filter records on one table by checking for the presence of multiple rows on an associated table?

For example, I have a table of images and another table identifying objects in that image:

```
 table: images

 id | url
----+--------------------------------
 1  | http://www.example.com/foo.png
 2  | http://www.example.com/bar.png
 3  | http://www.example.com/baz.png


 table: image_tags

 image_id | tag
----------+-------------
 1        | cats
 1        | living-room
 2        | beach
 2        | towel
 2        | dogs
 3        | cats
 3        | dogs
 3        | goldfish
```

If I wanted to query for all images that contain both `cats` and `dogs`, what would be the best way to approach this? What if I wanted images with `cats`, `dogs`, and `goldfish`?

One approach I've tried is to query for all `image_ids` of images containing dogs, then of those containing cats, and take the intersection. I can do this in my application but I was wondering if there was a way to run the same operation using SQL handling an arbitrary number of tags.

Comment: Could you please add your SQL queries to the question?

Comment: Have you considered normalizing the tags into their own table? That would make this question mostly trivial.

Comment: @DaneHillard . . . I fail to see how your suggestion would do anything other than introduce another `join` into any solution.  Normalization is probably a good idea, but not because it simplifies the answer to this question.

Comment: @DaneHillard they are normalized in the actual database, but I believe the problem would still remain. Instead of matching on strings, I'd just be matching on foreign key IDs. I used 2 tables instead of 3 in this example to make it a bit simpler.

Comment: @DaneHillard don't underestimate the cost of string comparisons... or the cost of also having to compensate for typos due to the same strings needing entered repeatedly.

Comment: Oh hell, I edited and still didn't address the proper person....long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to approach these types of queries ("set-within-set" queries) with `group by` and `having`:

```
select it.image_id
from image_tags it
where it.tag in ('cats', 'dogs')
group by it.image_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Note the "2" needs to equal the number of tags you want matched in the `in` list.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, although more verbose but perhaps more performant (?? - sorry don't have MySQL to test) than Gordon's answer is:

```
select i.id, i.url from images i where exists(
    select 1 from image_tags g where g.image_id=i.id and g.tag='cats'
)
and exists(
   select 1 from image_tags g where g.image_id=i.id and g.tag='dogs'
)
```

Comment: While this works, it is expecting exactly two tags to match against. To make it accept an arbitrary number of tags would require dynamically adding more sub-queries to the statement.

Comment: @AdamSheehan correct. I am not saying this is the right way to do it as it would be unbearably long to write and difficult to read but it shows a different way of expressing the same thing in SQL

Comment: But it's not expressing the same thing !?!?

Answer (score 0):

If you can supply the list as a comma separated string, this should work (but it may not translate well to a properly normalized table structure):

```
SET @tagCount := 1 + LENGTH([csvstring]) - LENGTH(REPLACE([csvstring], ',', '');

SELECT it.image_id, SUM(IF(FIND_IN_SET(it.tag, [csvstring])=0,0,1)) AS matches
FROM image_tags AS it
HAVING matches = @tagCount
;
```

Or alternatively...

```
SET @tagCount := 1 + LENGTH([csvstring]) - LENGTH(REPLACE([csvstring], ',', '');

SELECT it.image_id, COUNT(1) AS matches
FROM image_tags AS it
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(it.tag, [csvstring]) > 0
GROUP BY it.image_id
HAVING matches = @tagCount
;
```

With a more normalized structure, this could be a good bet:

```
SELECT it.image_id, COUNT(1) AS matches
FROM tags AS t 
   INNER JOIN image_tags AS it USING (tag_id)
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(t.tag_string, [csvstring]) > 0
GROUP BY it.image_id
HAVING matches = @tagCount
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a “Scuttle” solution

http://tagging.pui.ch/post/37027745720/tags-database-schemas

And

SELECT b.*
FROM scBookmarks b, scCategories c
WHERE c.bId = b.bId
AND (c.category IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
GROUP BY b.bId
HAVING COUNT( b.bId )=3

Or

SELECT b.*
FROM scBookmarks b, scCategories c
WHERE c.bId = b.bId
AND (c.category IN ('bookmark', 'webservice', 'semweb'))
GROUP BY b.bId

And minus

SELECT b. *
FROM scBookmarks b, scCategories c
WHERE b.bId = c.bId
AND (c.category IN ('bookmark', 'webservice'))
AND b.bId NOT
IN (SELECT b.bId FROM scBookmarks b, scCategories c WHERE b.bId = c.bId AND c.category = 'semweb')
GROUP BY b.bId
HAVING COUNT( b.bId ) =2

These code examples are directly from the website. You will need to adjust accordingly